# merging nested objects with lodash

Tags: merge, nested, lodash

I have a nested dataset describing a company's products and their respective orders (see exhibit 1).  I'm formatting it to send back to the front-end and I need some ideas about merging the repeated orders and order_details columns.

A product has a one to many relationship with orders via order_details, so a product can have many orders, and an order has one details table.

I'd like to merge orders and order details into something like exhibit 2.  Note that I'm pulling all products so in reality there are 77 of Exhibit 1's

**Exhibit 1**

```
[{
      productID: 1,
      productName: 'chips',
      categoryID: 3,
      orders: [{
       dataValues: [
         { 
            OrderID: 1,
            CustomerID: 'Blaus',
            EmployeeID: '9',
            order_details: [{
             dataValues: [
              {
               orderID: 1,
               productID: 1,
               orderAmount: 12
              }
             ]
            }]
        },
         { 
            orderID: 3, 
            CustomerID: 'Gerd', 
            EmployeeID: '10',
            order_details: [{
             dataValues: [
              {
               orderID: 1,
               productID: 1,
               orderAmount: 12
              }
             ]
            }]
         }
       ]
      }]

  }];
```

**Exhibit 2**

```
[{
    productID: 1,
    productName: chips,
    categoryID: 3,
    OrderID: [1, 3]
    CustomerID: ['Blaus','Gerd']
    EmployeeID: ['9', '10']
    orderID: [1, 3] 
    productID: [1, 1]
    orderAmount: [12, 12]
}]
```

Comment: show what you've tried of course

Comment: thanks thomas, think you've seen my other work

Comment: k. i'm taking a look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lodash deep merge ontop of existing collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651764/lodash-deep-merge-ontop-of-existing-collection)